# Choose a pair from two arrays

Tags: algorithm

Given 2 arrays A and B of length n and m respectively.

I want to find a pair (A[i],B[j]) such that sum A[i]+B[j] is maximum but under the condition that j-i>k for a given integer k and 1 <= i <= n, 1 <= j <= m.

I know a simple O(n*m) naive approach to solve it.But is their any better way to do this.?

Let me give an example say we have two arrays A= [5,10,9,7,10] and B=[0,0,0,4,1,2,-2] and say K=3 then i have to choose one element from A and other from B such that difference between the positions of chosen elements is atleast k.In this case we can see ans is 12. By choosing 2nd element from A and 6th element from B.

Hope it make it clear to understand the question

Comment: use dynamic programming :) create array maxB with length m, index i of maxB indicate the maximum value from i to m of array B. maxB can easily done in O(n) by maxB[i] = max(B[i], maxB[i +1]). then you just iterate through A elements max = max(A[i] + maxB[i + k] , max) . Complexity is O(n)

Comment: Can u make it more clear by above example.?Thnx in advance.How maxB can be done in O(n).It should be rather O(m) i guess

Comment: In your example, maxB = {4,4,4,4,2,2,-2}; so starting from i = 1 to 5 in A, we have max = A[1] + maxB[1 + (K + 1)] = 9, then for i = 2, max= A[2] + maxB[2 + (K +1)] = 12... we have max = 12 :) n is constant, so should be O(max(n,m))

Comment: Why isn't the max 14: B[3] + A[1] = 4 + 10 = 14, j - i = 2 < k = 3.

Comment: Because of condition j - i > k, i think you have some misunderstanding :)

Comment: haha, fail. thanks for pointing that out. That makes things easier, and you can do it in O(max(n,m)) like you say.

Comment: Do you limit `j-i` or `abs(j-i)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is way to do it in `O(N+M)` :-

Generate a max array where max[i] denotes maximum element in subarray b[i to m]

```
max[m] = b[m]        
 for(i=m-1;i>=1;i--) 
    max[i] = maximum(max[i+1],b[i]);
```

Calculate maxpair for all valid pairs as follows:-

```
maxpair = -infinity;


for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {

  if(i+k+1<=m) {

     maxpair = maximum(maxpair,a[i]+max[i+k+1]);

  }

}
```